# Different Lables with Different set of stocks

Tags: python, pine-script

```
    I modified following public screener pine script .script is 
stock = input(title="Stock List", defval="1-10", options=["1-10","11-20","21-30", "31-40", "41-50", "51-60", "61-70", "71-80", "81-90", "91-100"])


rsi_length     = input(14, title = "RSI Length")
rsi_overbought = input(0, title = "RSI Overbought Level")
// Insert Stock Symbol of your screener list
EX = "MYX_DLY:"

stock1   = EX + "COMFORT"
stock2   = EX + "PCHEM"
stock3   = EX + "RUBEREX"
stock4   = EX + "HLT"
stock5   = EX + "PNEPCB"
stock6   = EX + "SCGM"
stock7   = EX + "TGUAN"
stock8   = EX + "DAIBOCI"
stock9   = EX + "SAM"
stock10  = EX + "PIE"
stock11  = EX + "ANNJOO"
stock12  = EX + "CMSB"
stock13  = EX + "ULICORP"
stock14  = EX + "KOBAY"
stock15  = EX + "VITROX"
stock16  = EX + "UWC"
stock17  = EX + "JTIASA"
stock18  = EX + "JFTECH"
stock19  = EX + "MICROLN"
stock20  = EX + "HTPADU"
stock21  = EX + "MPI"
stock22  = EX + "KESM"
stock23  = EX + "FRONTKN"
stock24  = EX + "NOTION"
stock25  = EX + "PENTA"
stock26  = EX + "HONGSENG"
stock27  = EX + "MFCB"
stock28  = EX + "PPB"
stock29  = EX + "PANAMY"
stock30  = EX + "KAWAN"
stock31  = EX + "KAREX"
stock32  = EX + "OCNCASH"
stock33  = EX + "DLADY"
stock34  = EX + "CARLSBG"
stock35  = EX + "BAT"
stock36  = EX + "AJI"
stock37  = EX + "MBMR"
stock38  = EX + "MRDIY"
stock39  = EX + "LIIHEN"
stock40  = EX + "AMWAY"
stock41  = EX + "HARTA"
stock42  = EX + "SUPERMX"
stock43  = EX + "TOPGLOV"
stock44  = EX + "CAREPLS"
stock45  = EX + "KOSSAN"
stock46  = EX + "ADVENTA"
stock47  = EX + "IHH"
stock48  = EX + "PHARMA"
stock49  = EX + "KOTRA"
stock50  = EX + "OPTIMAX"
stock51  = EX + "OIB"
stock52  = EX + "MAHSING"
stock53  = EX + "YNHPROP"
stock54  = EX + "SPSETIA"
stock55  = EX + "IOIPG"
stock56  = EX + "SYMLIFE"
stock57  = EX + "UEMS"
stock58  = EX + "UOADEV"
stock59  = EX + "HENGYUAN"
stock60  = EX + "PETRONM"
stock61  = EX + "WASEONG"
stock62  = EX + "PENERGY"
stock63  = EX + "DIALOG"
stock64  = EX + "ARMADA"
stock65  = EX + "DAYANG"
stock66  = EX + "YINSON"
stock67  = EX + "UZMA"
stock68  = EX + "GAMUDA"
stock69  = EX + "IJM"
stock70  = EX + "EKOVEST"
stock71  = EX + "SUNCON"
stock72  = EX + "WCEHB"
stock73  = EX + "MUHIBAH"
stock74  = EX + "HLBANK"
stock75  = EX + "MAYBANK"
stock76  = EX + "BURSA"
stock77  = EX + "AMBANK"
stock78  = EX + "HLCAP"
stock79  = EX + "MANULFE"
stock80  = EX + "AEONCR"
stock81  = EX + "RCECAP"
stock82  = EX + "LPI"
stock83  = EX + "PBBANK"
stock84  = EX + "TAKAFUL"
stock85  = EX + "HLFG"
stock86  = EX + "ABMB"
stock87  = EX + "CIMB"
stock88  = EX + "TIMECOM"
stock89  = EX + "DIGI"
stock90  = EX + "TM"
stock91  = EX + "AXIATA"
stock92  = EX + "AMTEL"
stock93  = EX + "MAXIS"
stock94  = EX + "BINACOM"
stock95  = EX + "OPCOM"
stock96  = EX + "MISC"
stock97  = EX + "LITRAK"
stock98  = EX + "WPRTS"
stock99  = EX + "AIRPORT"
stock100 = EX + "SCIENTX"


////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//Selection 1 - Start

s_1 = if stock == "1-10"
    input(stock1 , type=input.symbol)
    
else
    if stock =="11-20"
        input(stock2 , type=input.symbol)
    else
        if stock =="21-30"
            input(stock3 , type=input.symbol)
        else
            if stock =="31-40"
                input(stock4 , type=input.symbol)
            else
                if stock =="41-50"
                    input(stock5 , type=input.symbol)
                else
                    if stock =="51-60"
                        input(stock6 , type=input.symbol)
                    else
                        if stock =="61-70"
                            input(stock7 , type=input.symbol)
                        else
                            if stock =="71-80"
                                input(stock8 , type=input.symbol)
                            else
                                if stock =="81-90"
                                    input(stock9 , type=input.symbol)  
                                else
                                    if stock =="91-100"
                                        input(stock10 , type=input.symbol)
    
//Selection 1 - End
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//Selection 2 - Start

s_2 = if stock == "1-10"
    input(stock11 , type=input.symbol)
    
else
    if stock =="11-20"
        input(stock12 , type=input.symbol)
    else
        if stock =="21-30"
            input(stock13 , type=input.symbol)
        else
            if stock =="31-40"
                input(stock14 , type=input.symbol)
            else
                if stock =="41-50"
                    input(stock15 , type=input.symbol)
                else
                    if stock =="51-60"
                        input(stock16 , type=input.symbol)
                    else
                        if stock =="61-70"
                            input(stock17 , type=input.symbol)
                        else
                            if stock =="71-80"
                                input(stock18 , type=input.symbol)
                            else
                                if stock =="81-90"
                                    input(stock19 , type=input.symbol)  
                                else
                                    if stock =="91-100"
                                        input(stock20 , type=input.symbol)
    
//Selection 2 - End
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//Selection 3 - Star

s_3 = if stock == "1-10"
    input(stock21 , type=input.symbol)
    
else
    if stock =="11-20"
        input(stock22 , type=input.symbol)
    else
        if stock =="21-30"
            input(stock23 , type=input.symbol)
        else
            if stock =="31-40"
                input(stock24 , type=input.symbol)
            else
                if stock =="41-50"
                    input(stock25 , type=input.symbol)
                else
                    if stock =="51-60"
                        input(stock26 , type=input.symbol)
                    else
                        if stock =="61-70"
                            input(stock27 , type=input.symbol)
                        else
                            if stock =="71-80"
                                input(stock28 , type=input.symbol)
                            else
                                if stock =="81-90"
                                    input(stock29 , type=input.symbol)  
                                else
                                    if stock =="91-100"
                                        input(stock30 , type=input.symbol)
    
//Selection 3 - End
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//Selection 4 - Start

s_4 = if stock == "1-10"
    input(stock31 , type=input.symbol)
    
else
    if stock =="11-20"
        input(stock32 , type=input.symbol)
    else
        if stock =="21-30"
            input(stock33 , type=input.symbol)
        else
            if stock =="31-40"
                input(stock34 , type=input.symbol)
            else
                if stock =="41-50"
                    input(stock35 , type=input.symbol)
                else
                    if stock =="51-60"
                        input(stock36 , type=input.symbol)
                    else
                        if stock =="61-70"
                            input(stock37 , type=input.symbol)
                        else
                            if stock =="71-80"
                                input(stock38 , type=input.symbol)
                            else
                                if stock =="81-90"
                                    input(stock39 , type=input.symbol)  
                                else
                                    if stock =="91-100"
                                        input(stock40 , type=input.symbol)
    
//Selection 4 - End
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


//Selection 5 - Start

s_5 = if stock == "1-10"
    input(stock41 , type=input.symbol)
    
else
    if stock =="11-20"
        input(stock42 , type=input.symbol)
    else
        if stock =="21-30"
            input(stock43 , type=input.symbol)
        else
            if stock =="31-40"
                input(stock44 , type=input.symbol)
            else
                if stock =="41-50"
                    input(stock45 , type=input.symbol)
                else
                    if stock =="51-60"
                        input(stock46 , type=input.symbol)
                    else
                        if stock =="61-70"
                            input(stock47 , type=input.symbol)
                        else
                            if stock =="71-80"
                                input(stock48 , type=input.symbol)
                            else
                                if stock =="81-90"
                                    input(stock49 , type=input.symbol)  
                                else
                                    if stock =="91-100"
                                        input(stock50 , type=input.symbol)
    
//Selection 5 - End
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//Selection 6 - Start

s_6 = if stock == "1-10"
    input(stock51 , type=input.symbol)
    
else
    if stock =="11-20"
        input(stock52 , type=input.symbol)
    else
        if stock =="21-30"
            input(stock53 , type=input.symbol)
        else
            if stock =="31-40"
                input(stock54 , type=input.symbol)
            else
                if stock =="41-50"
                    input(stock55 , type=input.symbol)
                else
                    if stock =="51-60"
                        input(stock56 , type=input.symbol)
                    else
                        if stock =="61-70"
                            input(stock57 , type=input.symbol)
                        else
                            if stock =="71-80"
                                input(stock58 , type=input.symbol)
                            else
                                if stock =="81-90"
                                    input(stock59 , type=input.symbol)  
                                else
                                    if stock =="91-100"
                                        input(stock60 , type=input.symbol)
    
//Selection 6 - End
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//Selection 7 - Start

s_7 = if stock == "1-10"
    input(stock61 , type=input.symbol)
    
else
    if stock =="11-20"
        input(stock62 , type=input.symbol)
    else
        if stock =="21-30"
            input(stock63 , type=input.symbol)
        else
            if stock =="31-40"
                input(stock64 , type=input.symbol)
            else
                if stock =="41-50"
                    input(stock65 , type=input.symbol)
                else
                    if stock =="51-60"
                        input(stock66 , type=input.symbol)
                    else
                        if stock =="61-70"
                            input(stock67 , type=input.symbol)
                        else
                            if stock =="71-80"
                                input(stock68 , type=input.symbol)
                            else
                                if stock =="81-90"
                                    input(stock69 , type=input.symbol)  
                                else
                                    if stock =="91-100"
                                        input(stock70 , type=input.symbol)
    
//Selection 7 - End
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//Selection 8 - Start

s_8 = if stock == "1-10"
    input(stock71 , type=input.symbol)
    
else
    if stock =="11-20"
        input(stock72 , type=input.symbol)
    else
        if stock =="21-30"
            input(stock73 , type=input.symbol)
        else
            if stock =="31-40"
                input(stock74 , type=input.symbol)
            else
                if stock =="41-50"
                    input(stock75 , type=input.symbol)
                else
                    if stock =="51-60"
                        input(stock76 , type=input.symbol)
                    else
                        if stock =="61-70"
                            input(stock77 , type=input.symbol)
                        else
                            if stock =="71-80"
                                input(stock78 , type=input.symbol)
                            else
                                if stock =="81-90"
                                    input(stock79 , type=input.symbol)  
                                else
                                    if stock =="91-100"
                                        input(stock80 , type=input.symbol)
    
//Selection 8 - End
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//Selection 9 - Start

s_9 = if stock == "1-10"
    input(stock81 , type=input.symbol)
    
else
    if stock =="11-20"
        input(stock82 , type=input.symbol)
    else
        if stock =="21-30"
            input(stock83 , type=input.symbol)
        else
            if stock =="31-40"
                input(stock84 , type=input.symbol)
            else
                if stock =="41-50"
                    input(stock85 , type=input.symbol)
                else
                    if stock =="51-60"
                        input(stock86 , type=input.symbol)
                    else
                        if stock =="61-70"
                            input(stock87 , type=input.symbol)
                        else
                            if stock =="71-80"
                                input(stock88 , type=input.symbol)
                            else
                                if stock =="81-90"
                                    input(stock89 , type=input.symbol)  
                                else
                                    if stock =="91-100"
                                        input(stock90 , type=input.symbol)
    
//Selection 9 - End
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//Selection 10 - Start

s_10 = if stock == "1-10"
    input(stock91 , type=input.symbol)
    
else
    if stock =="11-20"
        input(stock92 , type=input.symbol)
    else
        if stock =="21-30"
            input(stock93 , type=input.symbol)
        else
            if stock =="31-40"
                input(stock94 , type=input.symbol)
            else
                if stock =="41-50"
                    input(stock95 , type=input.symbol)
                else
                    if stock =="51-60"
                        input(stock96 , type=input.symbol)
                    else
                        if stock =="61-70"
                            input(stock97 , type=input.symbol)
                        else
                            if stock =="71-80"
                                input(stock98 , type=input.symbol)
                            else
                                if stock =="81-90"
                                    input(stock99 , type=input.symbol)  
                                else
                                    if stock =="91-100"
                                        input(stock100 , type=input.symbol)
    
//Selection 10 - End
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// Screener Function
screenerFunc() => 
    rsi  = rsi(close, 14) // Value
    cond =close[1]< open[1] and open < close and low > low[1] and close > high[1] and open >= close[1] and open < high[1] 
 or close[1]> open[1] and close < open and high < high[1] and close < low[1] and open < close[1] and open > low[1] 

    [rsi, cond]
    
     
 ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////   



////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////  
[value1, name1]   = security(s_1, timeframe.period, screenerFunc())
[value2, name2]   = security(s_2, timeframe.period, screenerFunc())
[value3, name3]   = security(s_3, timeframe.period, screenerFunc())
[value4, name4]   = security(s_4, timeframe.period, screenerFunc())
[value5, name5]   = security(s_5, timeframe.period, screenerFunc())
[value6, name6]   = security(s_6, timeframe.period, screenerFunc())
[value7, name7]   = security(s_7, timeframe.period, screenerFunc())
[value8, name8]   = security(s_8, timeframe.period, screenerFunc())
[value9, name9]   = security(s_9, timeframe.period, screenerFunc())
[value10, name10] = security(s_10, timeframe.period, screenerFunc())

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

cs1 = if name1
    s_1 + '  =  '+tostring(value1)
cs2 = if name2
    s_2 + '  =  '+tostring(value2)
cs3 = if name3
    s_3 + '  =  '+tostring(value3)
cs4 = if name4
    s_4 + '  =  '+tostring(value4)    
cs5 = if name5
    s_5 + '  =  '+tostring(value5)
cs6 = if name6
    s_6 + '  =  '+tostring(value6)
cs7 = if name7
    s_7 + '  =  '+tostring(value7)
cs8 = if name8
    s_8 + '  =  '+tostring(value8)    
cs9 = if name9
    s_9 + '  =  '+tostring(value9)
cs10 = if name10
    s_10 + '  =  '+tostring(value10)    


////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
total_cs = cs1+'\n'+cs2+'\n'+cs3+'\n'+cs4+'\n'+cs5+'\n'+cs6+'\n'+cs7+'\n'+cs8+'\n'+cs9+'\n'+cs10

// Plot Label
lab_1 = label.new(
          bar_index, high, total_cs, 
          color=color.gray, 
          textcolor=color.black, 
          style =  label.style_labeldown,
          yloc = yloc.price)

label.delete(lab_1[1]
```

So now result that i am getting is one set of stock at a time that has stock 1 to 10 or whichever set choose.so there is any possibilities that i can create different set of lables with different set of stocks in it.for example 10 different lables with each has specific set of stock.for example first lable with 1 to 10 stock,second lable with 11 to 20 stock and so on.....Appreciate any help in this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use lists. First of all, you should probably seek to improve your programming knowledge so you can get the skills to do the most basic things as the few ones I am showing you in this answer.

First, you can get the selection as an index, instead of a string:

```
EX = "MYX_DLY:"
stock_ranges = ["1-10","11-20","21-30", "31-40", "41-50", "51-60", "61-70", "71-80", "81-90", "91-100"]
# Building a dictionary to convert a validated string to an index (integer):
stock_range_dict = {v: i for i,v in enumerate(stock_ranges)}

stock = input(title="Stock List", defval="1-10", options=stock_ranges)
# Converting the input string to an index:
# This all was a "fix" but you should also probably change the return type.
idx_stock = stock_range_dict[stock]
```

Then, you can store your `stock1 to stock100` as elements in a list of 10 lists (of 10 elements each), instead of individual variables:

```
stock_groups = [["COMFORT" ,"PCHEM", "RUBEREX", "HLT", "PNEPCB", "SCGM", "TGUAN", "DAIBOCI", "SAM", "PIE"],
            ["ANNJOO", "CMSB","ULICORP","KOBAY","VITROX","UWC","JTIASA","JFTECH","MICROLN","HTPADU"],
            ["MPI","KESM", "FRONTKN","NOTION","PENTA","HONGSENG","MFCB","PPB","PANAMY","KAWAN"],
            ["KAREX","OCNCASH", "DLADY","CARLSBG","BAT","AJI","MBMR","MRDIY","LIIHEN","AMWAY"],
            ["HARTA","SUPERMX","TOPGLOV","CAREPLS","KOSSAN","ADVENTA","IHH","PHARMA","KOTRA","OPTIMAX"],
            ["OIB","MAHSING","YNHPROP","SPSETIA","IOIPG","SYMLIFE","UEMS","UOADEV","HENGYUAN","PETRONM"],
            ["WASEONG","PENERGY","DIALOG","ARMADA","DAYANG","YINSON","UZMA","GAMUDA","IJM","EKOVEST"],
            ["SUNCON","WCEHB","MUHIBAH","HLBANK","MAYBANK","BURSA","AMBANK","HLCAP","MANULFE","AEONCR"],
            ["RCECAP","LPI","PBBANK","TAKAFUL","HLFG","ABMB","CIMB","TIMECOM","DIGI","TM"],
            ["AXIATA","AMTEL","MAXIS","BINACOM","OPCOM","MISC","LITRAK","WPRTS","AIRPORT","SCIENTX"]]
```

Then instead of these monstruous towers of condition statements, you can do a function for your inputs, with the index of the wanted list and the initial selection index as parameters:

```
def get_input(initial_selection: int, list_idx: int):
    return input(EX + stock_groups[list_idx][initial_selection], type=input.symbol)
```

You would call it in a loop that is incrementing a counter:

```
# As list comprehension...
selections = [get_input(idx_sel, i) for i in range(10)]
```

or:

```
# as a for_loop:
selections = []
for i in range(10):
    selections.append(get_input(idx_stock, i))
```

Comment: marvellous.your skill is awesome.Yes your right i am newbie in coding.I am learning coding through experiences.I like your way how you project whole  new dimensions of script.To be frankly speaking its way out of my imagination.what you did it i haven't seen this coding level nowhere so i feel its difficult for me to finish this script where u left.I know its too much to ask but i loved to see full script made by you so ultimately i can enhanced my coding skill by looking at your coding level.Please if u can post whole script.Appreciate for what you i have did for this .

Comment: That's because you are using Pine script, it seems. The code I shared is in Python. I don't know Pine script. As said, I used some coding basics (arrays, functions, loops) that are available in most languages. For this level, it's really a matter of a few hours of learning and experimenting.

Comment: So that's python. That's why i said i haven't seen this coding nowhere.So pine script is different than python.Actually i was comparing your coding with other pine script coding.Never mind  but i like how you demonstrate other way of doing things.I wish pinescript don't have limitations to do this kind of  coding things .By the way thanks for your assistance even you don't  know pine script but still you tried to solve  my problem.Appreciate for everything